# Dynamic programming table - cleaner way to print out path?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dynamic-programming

This is my solution for the classic coin collection DP problem. When doing DP problems in general, I always find the `printPath()` step pretty awkward and messy, messier than the actual problem itself.

In this case, starting from the bottom-right corner, if the values in the directions up or left is a tie, just go up. Else, choose the direction that contains the greater value up or left. If we reach the first row, just keep going left. If we reach the first column, just keep going up.

Is there a cleaner way to do `printPath()`?

```
/*
given a grid
where o = coin
return the max coins you can get by only moving right or down
*/

var grid = [
  ['-','-','o','-','-','o'],
  ['-','-','-','o','-','-'],
  ['-','o','-','-','o','-'],
  ['-','-','-','o','-','-'],
  ['o','-','-','-','o','-'],
  ['-','-','o','-','-','o'],
];

function initTable(m, n, f) {
  var T = [];
  for (var r = 0; r < m; r++)
    T.push(Array(n).fill(f));
  return T;
}

function coinCollection(grid) {
  var m = grid.length, n = grid[0].length;

  var T = initTable(m+1, n+1, 0);

  for (var r = 1; r < m+1; r++) {
    for (var c = 1; c < n+1; c++) {
      var C = grid[r-1][c-1] === 'o' ? 1 : 0;
      T[r][c] = Math.max(T[r-1][c], T[r][c-1])+C;
    }
  }

  console.log({ T });

  printPath(T, m, n);

  return T[m][n];
}

function printPath(T, r, c) {
  var res = [];
  while (r !== 1 && c !== 1) {
    res.push([r, c]);
    if (T[r-1][c] === T[c][r-1] || T[r-1][c] > T[r][c-1]) {  // tie or up is more
      console.log(r, c, '↑');
      r--;
    } else {  // left is more
      console.log(r, c, '←');
      c--;
    }
  }
  if (r === 1) {  // hit first row, keep left until origin
    while (c !== 1) {  
      res.push([r, c]);
      console.log(r, c, '←');
      c--;
    }
  } else if (c === 1) {  // hit first col, keep up until origin
    while (r !== 1) {  
      res.push([r, c]);
      console.log(r, c, '↑');
      r--;
    }
  }
  console.log(r, c);
  res.push([r, c]);
  console.log({ grid, max_coins_path: res.map(([r,c]) => [r-1,c-1]).reverse() });
}

coinCollection(grid);
```

Comment: As the code apparently does what it it is supposed to do, the question might be better suited for [codereview.stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/); that being said, would it be an option to additionally store the path in an additional data structure instead of doing backtracking?